# How to keep code clean with template classes?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11

I have a template class like this :

```
template <class TType> class Class1;
```

and this class is used in many other classes :

```
class Class2 {
    Class1 _class1;    // How to pass the template parameter of Class1 in a clean way ?
};

// Same for Class3, Class4, ...
```

The problem is that the template parameter of Class1 must be chosen by client code so I can't put it directly like this :

```
class Class2 {
    Class1<OneType> _class1;    // Not correct, template parameter must be chosen by client code
};
```

So a correct way is to set Class2 as template class too :

```
template <class TTypeClass1> class Class2 {
    Class1<TTypeClass1> _class1;
};
```

The problem with this technic is that all classes using Class1 will have to be template classes so we pollute code of other classes to pass template parameter of Class1, and it even worse if these classes are composed of many template classes with many template parameters.

I found another way which is a little cleaner I think :

```
template <class TTypeClass1 /* And possible other parameters */> struct ClientConfiguration {
    // Declaration of EntityManager
    typedef Class1<TTypeClass1> Class1Typed;
};

// Configuration defined by client code
typedef ClientConfiguration<OneTypeForClass1 /* And possible other parameters */> CurrentClientConfiguration;

class Class2 {
    CurrentClientConfiguration::Class1Typed _class1;
}
```

But is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: _"But is there a better way to do this ?"_ Better by which means and requirements exactly? Why are you introducing variadic template parameters here? Could you clarify your question a bit please.

Comment: Your `ClientConfiguration` won't work the way you hope. You seem to assume that it would be possible to have different "instantiations" of `Class2` within the same program, compiled against different definitions of `CurrentClientConfiguration::Class1Typed`. If you actually attempt that, your program will violate One Definition Rule and therefore exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There is no variadic template, ... is just to indicate that we can have other parameters, I edited my question, sorry for the confusion. By better I mean maybe there is an "official way" to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: Your library code exhibits the all the usual drawbacks of any template code, namely, it must be shipped as header files and compiled by the user, but without the clarity and explicitness of normal template code. Class2 depends on user-supplied definitions, can you confirm or deny that just by looking at it? Also, how exactly do you plan to implement this `// Configuration defined by client code` bit? By `#include`ing a file, say, `usercode.h` and letting the user supply one? If that's the case you may omit templates altogether, just let the user make a few typedefs.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik CurrentClientConfiguration will be set once, there will not be more than one Class2. But yes, if the client code would like to have different versions of Class1, it will not be able to have the corresponding Class2. So it's not a correct solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I see a problem to be solved here. If class `A` references a parameterized type `B`, then `A` must itself be parameterized. Otherwise, you could (and should) just hard-code the type parameter in its reference to `B`. And if `A` must be parameterized, why jump through hurdles to try and find a more obfuscated way of expressing that? Admittedly the C++ compilation model with templates makes this spreading somewhat painful, but those are the semantics you have, and that's the way you express those semantics in C++.

Comment: @n.m. Yes my solution is bad, it's just hard-coding the type outside Class2.

Comment: @deong Ok thank you I believed there was maybe a way to do this in a less verbose way.

Comment: `template` type arguments are compile time arguments to some code.  Why did you choose compile time arguments and not run time?  If "performance", did you prove it was a bottleneck, or just assume and spew code?  If you have proven it to be a bottleneck, can the choice be type-erased?  Ie, can you abstract the part that is performance critical to a run-time interface, then inject that choice from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to recommend `Class1` inherit from an Abstract Base Class and you construct `Class2` (etc.), for example, with a factory to make the flavour of `Class1` you (or client) want.

However I think the better steer for what you seem to be after in this particular question might be to use traits?

```
struct TTrait_int {
    typedef int TClass1;
};
struct TTrait_float {
    typedef float TClass1;
};
template <class TRAITS>
class Class2 {
    Class1<typename TRAITS::TClass1> _class1;
};
...
Class2<TTrait_int> c2tta;
Class2<TTrait_float> c2ttb;
```

To be clear, this gives you **no** real benefit in the simple 1 template parameter case.

But it does scale *very* well...

You only ever need one `Class2` template parameter - the trait class: instead of a growing list of `Class2` template parameters you grow the suite of 'names' that this trait class must provision.

(If you want to lose even the single template parameter on `Class2` ... see instead my first sentence.)